# What app or program do I use to open a chat.db-wal file

Tags: macbook-pro

What program or app do I use to open a chat.db-wal file?

Comment: Which application is creating this file?

Comment: @nohillside Most likely iMessage. ~/Library/Messages

Answer (score 2):

*chat.db-wal* (besides chat.db and chat.db-shm) is a part of the sqlite3 database managing all your messages sent and received by the app Messages.

So the main app using this database as a "client" is Messages.

The purpose of the file chat.db-wal is to provide atomicity and durability in database systems by [write-ahead logging (WAL)](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html).

You can open the file explicitly by using any text editor (which I don't recommend) and implicitly by using a SQLite3 GUI like [DB Browser for SQLite 3.9.0](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) or [sqlitestudio 3.1.0](http://sqlitestudio.pl/).

---

Better create a copy of all database files and use these to tinker with them.

Comment: And the reason this doesn't have more upvotes is....?